# How to paginate Comments in Post in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5, pagination

The Scenario -
I'm assuming that i have thousands of Post and each post have 1-1000 comments. 
well i can simply paginate Post by 10 or 20 with its comments.
This will return paginated posts with its comments.

```
$Posts = \App\Post::where('published',true)->with('comments')->paginate(10);
```

The problem is that I want to paginate comments so each posts return 4 comments. Then how do I call other comments if a posts have more then 4 comments?

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way is to store posts on a separate table. For example create a post table using the following migration

```
Schema::create('posts', function(Blueprint $table){
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('title');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Now create comments table using migration:

```
   Schema::create('comments', function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('post_id')->unsigned();           
        $table->string('name');
        $table->text('comment_body');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('poem_id')->references('id')->on('posts'); 
    });
```

Create a one to many relations between these two tables as follows:

For `Post` model,

```
class Post extends Model
{
    ...     

    public function comments(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }
}
```

and for the `Comment` model,

```
class Comment extends Model
{
    protected $fillable =  ['post_id', 'c_body', 'name'];

    public function posts(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Poem', 'post_id');
    }   


}
```

At this point, after populating the two database tables: `posts` and `comments`, you can then query them separately in your controller. 
To do that, add the two lines at the top of your controller:
`use App\Post;`
`use App\Comment;`

now in any method of your choice in that controller, query posts and comments for each most as follows

```
public function index(){
    $posts = Post::where('published',true);
    $comments = Post::where('published',true)->comments;
   // pass this data to your view
   return view('anyview', compact('posts', 'comments');
}
```

My answer is long, though i tried to make it short. Hope it helped.